# Calling WriteRegMultiStr in NSIS properly

Tags: nsis

With version 3.02 of NSIS came the addition of the `WriteRegMultiStr` function. When the function is called in my script the script throws an error:

```
Usage: WriteRegMultiStr /REGEDIT5 rootkey subkey entry_name hex_string_like_660000000000
root_key=(HKCR[32|64]|HKLM[32|64]|HKCU[32|64]|HKU|HKCC|HKDD|HKPD|SHCTX)
```

The call itself looks like this:

`WriteRegMultiStr /REGEDIT5 HKLM "System\CurrentControlSet\Services\SomeService" "DependsOnService" "service1 service2"`

Since there is no documentation on this specific function which was added later on, long after `WriteRegStr` and `WriteRegDWORD` were available, I have to wonder - how does one use it?

So far with respect to entering `REG_MULTI_SZ` values I only found the directive to use a registry-NSIS -plugin. Yet the function exists, so how can it be used?

Addendum:

Encoding the string to hex and passing it with ot without quotation marks yields no desirable result either.

Comment: How can you say there is no documentation? The NSIS documentation has example code using this instruction.

Comment: Ahh yes, I remember that. Tried that sample code with an older version of NSIS which resulted in the sample not working. Did not remember it existed after updating to 3.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was actually able to find an answer after digging through the depths of the internet. Since I don't think this has been answered on StackOverflow I will leave a response here, in case anyone wants to use this function.

The structure of the command as described in the opening post is basically correct, but the value must be encoded precisely. My command looks like this:

`WriteRegMultiStr /REGEDIT5 HKLM "System\CurrentControlSet\Services\SomeService" "DependsOnService" 54,00,63,00,70,00,69,00,70,00,00,00,41,00,66,00,64`

For anyone intending to test this string, this is

```
Tcpip
Afd
```

encoded in hexadecimal regedit format. Precisely this is Regedit Version 5.0 format, as opposed to REGEDIT4 format. A conversion editor can be used to achieve this, I used OTConvertIt.

The script should then compile, assuming you run NSIS version 3.02 or higher.

Answer (score 1):

As you found out, the value data must be in the exact same format as .reg files from Windows 2000+.

The reason this instruction works this way is because it is actually the same as `WriteRegBin` under the hood and very little code was added to support this new functionality.

In the future you might be able to drop the `/REGEDIT5` switch and give it plain strings but support for that has not been added yet.

The [Registry plug-in](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Registry_plug-in) does allow you to write these strings in a sane manner.